# How to limit multi-Publisher can not listening the SAME Queue with the NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus, publisher

guys:
 I want to use NServiceBus to manage messages.I have more than 5 different Publishers,every publisher is listening different queue.and every publisher have more than 3 different Subscribers.

Currently,the publishers and their Subscribers works well.but unfortunately,i found some messages in which should be processed by one Publisher being received by other program which only know the queue's name.and the original Publisher didn't know that.
 So i want to know if there is any solution to prevent other program or Publisher receive myself messages?

Comment: Can you give an example of your problem? Like Publisher1 listens for Message1 on Queue1 and Publisher2 listens for Message2 on Queue2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be specific about who subscribes to what, then you need to manually configure the endpoint to subscribe to specific messages(Bus.Subscribe()/Bus.Unsubscribe()).  If you don't want a particular endpoint to receive certain messages even though they may show up then you can also load the specific handlers.  This can be done by separating the messages/handlers into separate assemblies and then loading the ones you want with Configure.With(assemblyList).